# Variable types global, static , local and auto

Tags: c++, c, function, variables

I want to developed a system in which want to keep track of an
event occurring frequently in the system. I can do this by calling
a function, increment the previous value of the
event-occurring-counter, and print its value and then return. To
accomplish this I need a variable which can retain its value even
after the function returns so that in the next call to the function
the previous value of the counter could be incremented by one and so
on.

According to your opinion, which type of variable we should use local,
global, static or auto? Support your answer with valid arguments.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? (I also didn't downvote, but don't expect that someone here will do your homework for you, show some effort)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but help the downvoter to say: you need to learn the language first, define the problem and come up with a solution, try it out. If it does not work, then come here and ask

Comment: Note that if you need to access the variable from outside the function (for example, from another function to print the counter), then it must be defined outside of a function (but should be `static` in a C file, or in the anonymous namespace in a C++ file). While you could design a function that either counted or printed according to some argument, it would not be a pretty design — a serious mixup in the purpose of the function.

Comment: One of these things doesn't belong. `local` is not a storage class in C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

Local and Auto are same the fourth type is register not local. You can't use auto since its variable are redefined every call.

Either global or static depending on the needs of your design. If you want to use the variable in some other file make it global.

```
int count; // outside the function calls
```

If you want the scope of it to be local to that function and increment for each time an event occurs make it static inside the function

```
static int count = 0; 
// variable is defined only once subsequent calls to it wont redefine it
```

you can make it global as well as static if you want the entire file to access it but not outside world.

```
 static int count = 0; // outside of any function calls.
```